# Crontab running the python program and python log file is not accessible as cron runs with sudo

Tags: cron, permission-denied, file-access

I have a cron setup using sudo crontab -e on my EC2 (Ubuntu) which runs a bashfile to execute my python program. The python program creates a log file. Now due to some error if my program closes and I run it from terminal it gives me error for access denied.

Comment: if you run crontab with sudo, the process will run as root user and the ownership of the file will belong to that user. Can your bash script have a `chown`/`chmod` command changing the ownership/permission of the log file?